# Last printf statement is being skipped

Tags: c, pointers, printf, scanf, dynamic-memory-allocation

After insertting all my values I was expecting to have the final printf statement give the final results of the equations

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *carModel; 
    float tankRange; 
    float gasCost; 
    float costTank; 
    float gallonsTank; //gallons in full tank
    float mpg; //miles per gallon
    float costMile;

    carModel = malloc(256);

    printf("What is the model of car? " );
    scanf("%255s", &carModel);  // Don't read more than 255 chars
    printf("How many miles can be driven on a full tank? " );
    scanf("%f", &tankRange);
    printf("What is the gas cost per gallon? " );
    scanf("%f", &gasCost);
    printf("How much does it cost to fill the tank? " );
    scanf("%f", &costTank);
    gallonsTank = costTank / gasCost;
    mpg = tankRange / gallonsTank;
    costMile = mpg / gasCost;
    printf("Amazing! %255s has an mpg of %.3f per gallon! You spent $%.2f to drive one mile!\n",  carModel, mpg, costMile);

return 0;

}
```

All of it prints and runs well except for the last printf statement, it shows that the code is finished running

Comment: Hint: where does `carModel` point to?

Comment: You're better using a constant like in my answer to the last version of this question than hard-coding the magic values 256 and 255.  Heap allocated memory carries with it a liability to explicitly free() it again.  It doesn't matter here but you want to make that a habit.

Comment: Prefer double to float.

Comment: Prefer initialized variables.  `char *carModel = malloc(...);`, `double gallonsTank = costTAnk / gasCost;`.  This also reduces scope as variables which makes your code easier to read and reason about.

Comment: If you operate on such small arrays and don't need longer lifetime than the function body you usually are better off with a local array: `char carModel[256];` Still be aware that these arrays decay to pointers implicitly, so again `scanf(..., &carModel);` would have been wrong (undefined behaviour for mismatching pointer types) even though, due to the equality of the addresses of `&carModel` and `&carModel[0]`, it would have been pretty likely that you would have experienced the desired result – so indeed the more natural way would in this case have hidden the error away, unfortunately :(

Comment: *'Prefer double to float'* – even better: avoid floating point entirely! You need to be aware that even many of such simple numbers like 0.1 (this one included) cannot be represented exactly as they are periodic in binary. Usually you are far better off with fixed comma arithmetic (i.e. doing calculations in sub-units like milliseconds instead of seconds, in cents instead of euros/dollars/... or 10th of, ...). Admitted, IO, if presented in whole units, gets more complicated, but in most cases you'll profit everywhere else from.

Answer (score 6):

This call of scanf is incorrect

```
printf("What is the model of car? " );
scanf("%255s", &carModel);  // Don't read more than 255 chars
               ^^^^^^^^^
```

instead you have to write

```
printf("What is the model of car? " );
scanf("%255s", carModel);  // Don't read more than 255 chars
```

Otherwise the call of `scanf` overwrites the memory occupied by the local variables.

The conversion specifier `s` expects an argument of the type `char *` while you are passing an argument of the type `char **`.

If you want to input a string that contains more than one word then you can write for example

```
printf("What is the model of car? " );
scanf("%255[^\n]", carModel);  // Don't read more than 255 chars
```

Pay attention to that you should free the allocated memory at the end of the program

```
free( carModel );
```